# Make sure loop is fully executed before running other code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem that a function keeps getting called before a loop finishes. How do I prevent the function from being called until after the loop finishes? My loop is outputting HTML tables to the page which is then being acted upon by my `sortResultsByDate`, but that can't happen until the HTML is rendered. Currently my second function is firing before the first one completes.

```
ns.executeUserSearch = function() {
    jQuery.each(searchInputArray, function(index, value) {
        ns.getUserSearchResults(searchInputArray, index);
    });

    ns.sortResultsByDate();
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve recursiveness?

Comment: This should work fine. However, is your `getUserSearchResults` making an ajax call to get the results? In this case, it won't work. Also as Technoh says, are you meaning to call `getUserSearchResults` from itself?

Comment: Try a jQuery deferred: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: Yes @Rhumborl, I'm making an AJAX call.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, I've updated my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're calling `ns.getUserSearchResults` recursively inside the `jQuery.each` loop. `ns.sortResultsByDate()` is being executed once for every such call, so you end up executing it multiple times before you complete all your recursive calls.